# How to specify different home screen icons for Android and IOS web app

Tags: android, ios, icons, homescreen

When someone adds to the home screen for a web mobile app - it is typically this code used to specify the home screen icon.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png"/>
```

How do I have Android and IOS select different icons for the home screen?

Comment: Check out https://www.favicon-generator.org/ , but basically: `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/android-icon-192x192.png">`

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying that the ' rel="icon" type="image/png"' will be selected by android devices? Have you tested this?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes. No.

Comment: You didnt answer my question in the comments... Yes? - No?

Comment: You wrote: _"Thanks. Are you saying that the ' rel="icon" type="image/png"' will be selected by android devices? Have you tested this?"_. I answered in the order you asked.

Comment: lol - ok - thanks... 
Do you drink beer?
 Can I buy you one?
What is 2 + 9?
;)